# Multiple browser window handle using Selenium driver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

My current assignment is to convert a web page into PDF using Selenium web driver.For that I have written the code and it is working fine.Now I want to implement Multi-threading in my code.I am using Google Chrome driver.
Suppose I am running 5 threads in a machine. So my code started capturing the PDF of latest window only. I am unable to generate PDF for rest of the windows.

**Note**: For PDF generation I am using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>>Microsoft Print to PDF option.

**Expected Result**: PDF generation for first window.Close the fist window.PDF generation for second window.Close the second window and so on.

**Actual Result** : PDF is getting generated for the fifth window.Closing the fifth window.PDF is getting generated for the fourth window.Closing the fourth window.PDF is getting generated for the third window.Closing the third window.
PDF is getting generated for the second window.Closing the second window.
PDF is getting generated for the first window.Closing the first window.But in my local drive I can see only two PDFs got generated.There should be five PDFs.

Comment: Please attach code snippet which includes sending the related key combo